# How to make Java read from port and store bytes in file very quickly?

Tags: java, performance, port

i a problem with java and how to import to file 1024000 numbers.
I created and application that reads data from port and store every number to a file as ascii character.
but it takes too long. java supose to be quicker. what should i change? should i use other libriries ? not FileOutputStream ?
as i tested now in 20 minuts i had 100.000 in my file....
Thank you

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {  

   if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)  
   {  
       try  
       {  
           int singleData = input.read();  

           if(index<=1024000)  
           {                 
               if(index==1024000 && singleData==42)
               {
                   logText = "End of data. "+index+" data received ";  
               }
               else
               {  
                   if (singleData != NEW_LINE_ASCII)  
                   {  
                       //  logText = Integer.valueOf(singleData).toString()+"\n";  
                       index++;  
                   }  

                   writeFile(singleData, fileName, false);  
               }         
           }  
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {  
           logText = "Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")";  
       }  
    }  
}  

public void writeFile(int data, String fileName, boolean endOfFile) throws IOException {  

    FileOutputStream xfos = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true);  
    DataOutputStream xdos = new DataOutputStream(xfos);  

    xdos.writeBytes(Integer.toString(data)+"\n");   // writes Ascii  

    xdos.close();  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is java writing to the file and the network, i.e. reading from the port?  And why are you opening the file and appending on each read? why not keep the file open while you are not done?

Comment: Open the file once and you should be able to write 40 MB in less than a second.

Answer (score 3):

Stop opening and closing the file for each entry, and start buffering.  Create a int[] to hold the integers as they come in, and only write after you have some significant number of them.  Additionally, depending on the environment, you could keep the streams open and only close them on exit (or 1024000 entries read).

Right now each time you get an integer, you open the file, run down to the end, write one line, then close it.  Opening and closing is expensive, and you could certainly write this so that it doesn't have to happen every time.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the output file open until you are done writing. Closing the file after each write causes the OS to write the single byte you just wrote to disk. This is slow no matter the language, its simply an effect of the guarantees that come with the file close operation. Also finding the end of the file each time you open it can also take quite some time the longer the file becomes.

Make use of the bulk read and write methods of the streams. Instead of reading and writing single characters, use a byte[] of reasonable size (8K = 8192 is usually plenty). Alternately make the streams buffered by wrapping them into BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream (slightly higher overhead, but simpler code).

In essence what you should do is open the input and the output streams once at the start, and keep both of them open until all the data is through. Using block transfers or buffered streams the main limiting factor will be the hardware (the serial port in your case).

Comment: Thank you all , but i believe that i open only one the input output stream in the begining. I have a button in GUI Connect tha t does this : connects to port initialize the streams

Comment: You haven't shown the code for *writeFile(singleData, fileName, false);* and thats the one we are suspecting you to open/close for each byte.

Comment: Thank you all for your advises. I changed my code and i used a buffer byte[] to get the data and then store them all together in a file. The time reduced incredible . it reads 1024001 data in 1.31 sec. The problem is can i make it quicker? i

Comment: You are now most likely limited by the interface's baud rate. Only way to go faster is increase the baud rate, provided the devices can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all , but i believe that i open only one the input output stream in the begining. I have a button in GUI Connect tha t does this : connects to port initialize the streams

```
    private void btnConnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        communicator.connect();
        if (communicator.getConnected() == true)
        {
            if (communicator.initIOStream() == true)
            {
                communicator.initListener();

            }
        }
    }


 //connect to the selected port in the combo box
public void connect()
{

 fileName="xxxx"+"_"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss").format(new Date())+".txt";
    String selectedPort = (String)window.cboxPorts.getSelectedItem();
    selectedPortIdentifier = (CommPortIdentifier)portMap.get(selectedPort);
    index=0;
    vec.clear();
    CommPort commPort = null;

    try
    {
        //the method below returns an object of type CommPort
        commPort = selectedPortIdentifier.open("TigerControlPanel", TIMEOUT);
        //the CommPort object can be casted to a SerialPort object
        serialPort = (SerialPort)commPort;
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        //for controlling GUI elements
        setConnected(true);
        window.txtLog.setText(null);
        //logging
        logText = selectedPort + " opened successfully.";
        window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.black);
        window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");

    }
    catch (PortInUseException e)
    {
        logText = selectedPort + " is in use. (" + e.toString() + ")";

        window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.RED);
        window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
           if(selectedPort==null)
           {  
            logText = " No port selected";

           }else 
            logText = "Failed to open " + selectedPort + "(" + e.toString() + ")";
        window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
        window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
}

//open the input and output streams
public boolean initIOStream()
{
    //return value for whather opening the streams is successful or not
    boolean successful = false;

    try {
        //
        input = serialPort.getInputStream();
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        successful = true;
        return successful;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logText = "I/O Streams failed to open. (" + e.toString() + ")";
        window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.red);
        window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
        return successful;
    }
}

//starts the event listener that knows whenever data is available to be read
public void initListener()
{
    try
    {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    }
    catch (TooManyListenersException e)
    {
        logText = "Too many listeners. (" + e.toString() + ")";
        window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.red);
        window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
    }
    try {
        output.write(messageString.getBytes());
      // output.write(System.getProperty("java.library.path").getBytes()) ;

    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

Comment: Even when i commented the lines to save to a file it took me a long time to get the data from port. In a minute i had read 9380 .not enought. so i believe the problem is starting from how quickly i read the data. Storing them in a file it's another think i have to check afterwards.
So is there something to make the reading quicker? should i use another library?
thank you

Comment: Since youre using RS232 interface, how about setting a higher baud rate? I see no initialization in your code where you set any of the interface parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your advises. I changed my code and i used a buffer byte[] to get the data and then store them all together in a file. The time reduced incredible . it reads 1024001 data in 1.31 sec. The problem is can i make it quicjer? it 's only numbers it should take only seconds. here is the code

```
    if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
    {

     int    available =0;
     int bytesRead;
    try {

        available = input.available();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024001];

            try {
        while ( (bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
             byte[] newData = new byte[data.length + bytesRead];
         // copy data previously read
         System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
        // append data newly read
         System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newData, data.length, bytesRead);
         // discard the old array in favour of the new one
         data = newData;
         if(data.length==1024001)
              {
                     logText = "End of data. "+data.length+" data received "+fileName;
                 window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                 window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
                 writeFile(data, fileName, false);
                    }  
            bytesRead++;
```

i have also  set these parameters for port

```
               serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
```

is there a way to set the serial port speed to full?

Comment: Maximum baud rate is determined by the hardware (both ends of the cable must be capable of the baud rate, so the slower device is the limit). You can just double the rate until you no longer get a connection, the last speed that worked will be the limit. Or just make it configurable. 115200 should be supported by almost any device nowadays, it *may* go much much higher, some devices may handle up to 3mbit/s. The cable quality and length can also be a limiting factor.